# Sugestão de texto

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estou criando um formulário e gostaria de saber alguma forma onde eu começo a digitar uma palavra e ela começa a me mostra sugestões, idêntico como funciona o de compras de viagem no aeroporto ou em sites diversos

Comment: O nome disto é _type ahead_ ou _auto complete_ mesmo. Isso responde sua dúvida?

Comment: Olha para isso você vai precisar usar Ajax, da uma olhada neste link e ve se te ajuda! https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_suggest_php

Answer (score 5):

O nome disso é *autocomplete* onde há um evento detectando a escrita , com isso é feito uma busca em um conjunto de dados já buscados do banco de dados ou outro local.

Com isso é criado um componente para mostrar esses dados que casam com o que foi digitado até o momento.

Encontrei esse componente :

**Datalist** [1]

Ele recebe um conjunto de opções para serem mostradas , essa é um forma para fazer algo prático sem muitas complicações.

```html
<label for="browser">Qual navegador está utilizando?</label>
<input id="browser" list="browsers" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Mas se quer algo mais customizado sugiro imlementar com javascript ( jquery ) e ajax para buscar do banco o popular seu componente.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar uma API de *autocomplete* do JQuery para isso.
Segue um código de exemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableCountrys = [
      "Argentina",
      "Argélia",
      "Alemanha",
      "Brasil",
      "Chile",
      "Colômbia",
      "Equador"
    ];
    $( "#country" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableCountrys
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <label for="country">País: </label>
  <input id="country">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Maiores detalhes na [documentação](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).